# When i use mount in enzyme, the nested button component click handler is "undefined" why is this?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

**The problem:**

OnClick is 'undefined' in the console.log inside my test. Why is this?

I can do button.simulate('click') and the test will pass, should it not fail?

**App.js**

```js
const App = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div data-test="component-app">
      <h1 data-test="counter-display">The counter is currently {counter}</h1>
      <ButtonContainer data-test="increment-button" handleClick={handleClick}>
        Increment
      </ButtonContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**ButtonContainer**

```js
const ButtonContainer = props => {
  return (
    <button
    data-test="increment-button"
    onClick={props.handleClick}
  >
    Increment
  </button>
  );
};
```

**Test**

```js
test("button", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<App />);
  const button = wrapper.find('button')
  console.log(button.props().onClick[0])
});
```

Comment: Presumably because `props.handleNext` doesn't exist? But you're not showing the code that proves it does, so we can't really tell you anymore more than that.

Comment: I'll fix the description. But handleNext comes from the "main" component and it does exist

Comment: We still have no way to say, because it's impossible to tell whether `handleNext` is anything in the context that you're declaring `<UploadPortal...>`: please turn this into a [mcve] that shows all the relevant code (and none of the irrelevant code).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have removed everything and added a simpler example now. Let me know if this works

Comment: Why `button.props().onClick[0]` instead of `button.props().onClick`? You're passing a (const-declared) function, not an array?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans becausse when I do button.prop(), I see the following:          {
      'data-test': 'increment-button',
      onClick: [Function: handleClick],
      children: 'Increment'
    }

Comment: Yes... that's the string representation of a function in Node? That's not "an array with a Function in it." and you can very easily show yourself that fact by running `node` and then typing `console.log(function test() {})`: notice what the output is.

Comment: so is this why it is "undefined"?

Comment: yes, of course. `onClick` is a function, but you're trying to access it as if it's an array. Functions are objects in JS, so you're basically asking for the function's property "0", which is undefined, in the same way that `const f = function test(){}; console.log(f[0])` is 100% legal code, but will print "undefined" because there is no property "0"

Comment: ahh got it, that makes sense. thanks! not sure how I can make this answer as correct answer to my initial question, but i get it now

Comment: As a question that's effectively about a typo, honestly it's better to delete it again, because there's nothing in this question that'll benefit future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You should log `button.props().onClick`, it's **NOT** an array.

E.g.

`App.test.jsx`:

```js
import App from './app';

describe('61895053', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    const button = wrapper.find('button');
    console.log(button.props().onClick);
  });
});
```

The outcome of the test:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/61895053/App.test.jsx
  61895053
    ✓ should pass (59ms)

  console.log
    [Function: handleClick]

      at Object.<anonymous> (stackoverflow/61895053/App.test.jsx:7:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        4.025s, estimated 10s
```

Comment: As what is basically a typo, this should have been a comment. And it was. I ran them through that.